# Adjectives after nouns

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, poetry

> Just in that farthermost angle, where
>
> You see the remains of a winding-stair,
>
> One turret especially high in air
>
> Uprear’d its tall gaunt form;
>
> As if defying the power of Fate, or
>
> The hand of ‘Time the Innovator;’
>
> And though to the pitiless storm
>
> Its weaker brethren all around
>
> Bowing, in ruin had strew’d the ground,
>
> Alone it stood, while its fellows lay strew’d,
>
> Like a four-bottle man in a company **‘screw’d**,’
>
> Not firm on his legs, but by no means subdued.

In this poem, what does bolded strew'd describe? A man or a company?

Comment: I think my answer below is complete, but this sort of question might be better suited for the [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sister site. Interpreting a poem like this is an advanced topic even for native speakers and not something a typical English language learner will encounter.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about "strew'd" but bolded "screw'd." I assume you're asking about the latter.

"Screw'd" (short for "screwed") describes "a company." In the 1800s, ["screwed" was slang for "very drunk."](http://www.pitt.edu/~emk4/comp1/screw.html) In turn, "company" here means a group of people. A "four-bottle man" is a person who regularly drinks four bottles of liquor (probably wine) and who therefore has a high alcohol tolerance.

A modern (and un-poetic) rough translation of the line might be "like a habitual drinker left standing after the rest of the group passed out drunk."